# Using English with Equation trained data tesseract tess4j

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I'm trying to read an image with mathematical equations using tess4j in java. However, I think its overlapping the characters and not able to combine English with Equations. Is this a trained data issue? How can I fix this. Below is my code .

```
 ITesseract tess = new Tesseract();
        try {
            tess.setLanguage("eng+equ");
            String imageURL = "http://www.blah.com/images/test-exercises/exercises.png";
            URL url = new URL(imageURL);
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
            String result = tess.doOCR(img);
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Output that I get

```
a) ↥⊝≍⋉↥⋮↥↸⊣⊽≍ k) ↥⋅⊈⋉⇣≁⇃⋅↸≍⋉⇣⋮↸⋅∠⊽≁≍
⊔ ⇃⋅↸
3x ↸≍ ↸ e
7 4:7, ≓ ≓ z, 77
b) 1+ 1 1 1) 3” z») ∙≁−−
↥ ↥ ⋅
r) 17:71:3770 m) ≩∅⊣⇇⋜∅≁↥≻⊣∅≁⊈⋗⋉↖⋮↼↴
3 .
d) ↼↴≍⊣⋜⋮↥↥≍⋉↥∘ n) ⊈⇉≁≍⋮≹⋜⋉⊢⇃⋅∖⊢⊢≩≍≻
9) Liz: o) ⇇⋜↨≍≁⊈⋅↸⋮↥∘⋅−≁⊈⋉↥≟≍
```

[image: Image Used for testing]

Comment: Please attach original image.

Comment: Edited the question with image. The url mentioned in the code is dummy. The actual url contained this image